# how to replace the given string using preg_replace() in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the string by following code

```
$find2 = array ('/is/', '/working/'); 
 $replace2 = array ('to', 'work');
 $data="During the day, Damien is working";
 echo  preg_replace ($find2, $replace2, $data);
```

output is

> During the day, Damien to work

but i want the result to be

> Damien to work

Comment: This code doesn't do anything that would remove `"During the day"`. What exactly have you tried to accomplish that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
$data="During the day, Damien is working";
echo preg_replace("/.*,(.*)/i","$1",$data);
```

**Output:**

> Damien is working

would work. It will remove  "Anything, String"  to "String".Removing everything before "," along with ",".

---

For your code, You want the data array to replace the two things + you want a replacement as well along with it  as i  understand.
So,

**Code:**

```
$find2 = array ('/is/', '/working/',"/.*,(.*)/"); 
 $replace2 = array ('to', 'work',"$1");
 $data="During the day, Damien is working";
 echo  preg_replace ($find2, $replace2, $data);
```

**Output:**

> Damien to work

Comment: is working fine. can we replace "Damien to work" instead of "Damien is working" as well ?

Comment: Regular expression is an overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace "During the day, " with ''.

Comment: Another way to remove a string other than removing it?

Comment: is there any other way to replace instead of this "During the day, " with ''.

Comment: You can use the str_replace function. For what you've asked us, it would be better than preg_replace.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i need only in regular expression method.

Comment: why only regular expressions?

Comment: @ScottSaunders  , He is not preg_replacing one string, if you look carefully, he is substituting two other things as well.!!

Comment: @ngen: He hasn't explained his real problem at all. I have the feeling he's doing some homework that he has no clue how to code.

Comment: @ScottSaunders he tried his best when he coded to replace "is" to "to" and another change as well. str_replace will be very inefficient on multiple replacements.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  It is a solution to the problem which is a lot more simple than a hard coded `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 1):

To remove `During the day, Damien is working` you can use the following:

```
$data = str_ireplace('During the day, Damien is working', 'Damien to work', $data);
```

So that:

```
$data = "During the day, Damien is working";
$data = str_ireplace('During the day, Damien is working', 'Damien to work', $data);
echo $data;
```

will echo (output):

```
Damien to work
```

as you requested.

Comment: @BrunoThileeban, Regular expressions are far more expensive than a simple `str_ireplace()` function. I'm not going to suggest you a uglier way to do what I explained above.

Comment: @Jeffrey What will you do , when the name changes to "Jeffrey" instead of "Damien" ?. Will you rewrite the code?.

Comment: sorry.It is one of my interview question.that's why am asking.

Comment: @ngen, nothing simpler: `$name = "Damien"; $data = str_ireplace("During the day, $name is working", "$name to work", $data);`. Regex is simply not the solution here.

Comment: if "working" changes to "running" ?. Will you keep writing str_replace?.

Comment: @ngen, do you have any clue about what PHP is? The same variable you would be using for regex you can use in the str_ireplace() function. Keep saying things like "what if..." will not change that. The author didn't explained what his problem is so we really don't know what part of the string must be constant and what will be variable. Plus, if you know PHP you know that regular expressions are one of the slowest functions out there. Using it here is just an overkill. Just saying.

Comment: @Jeffrey , I wasn't trying to flame this topic. I do know that it's slow, but regex is more code friendly when the content is dynamic. And two lines of regex replaced some lines of str_replace and vice versa wont change the complexity anyways. ;-) . I just gave what the guy asked .

Comment: @ngen, I understand, but regex is the evil for PHP. You can ask anyone and they will they you that whenever it is possible to avoid regex you should do it. Have a nice day sir.